# Check radio button if other radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have this function on click:

```
    $('#style_2').click(function() {
        if($('#checkbox_1').is(':checked')) {
        alert("it's checked"); 
        $('input[name=checkbox_5]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                                               }
                                            });
```

What should happen is:

- User click "style_2"
- If "checkbox_1" is checked at the same time, then it should check "checkbox_5"

I get the alert, so something is right here, but it does not check "checkbox_5".

Comment: Next time please click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet to make a [mcve]

Comment: If the radio buttons have the same `name` attribute you get this behaviour by default with no need for JS